# Modular surface of tri-focal Cassini curve ContourPlot3D missing feet

Tags: plotting

I am wondering why the following fails to cover the surface at points near $k = 0$.

```
c[z_] := (z + 1) (z - 1) (z + 1 + I);

ContourPlot3D[Abs[c[x + I y]] == k^3, {x, -2.5, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
{k, 0, 1.75}, Background -> White, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "k"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Furthermore, when the left hand side is complex expanded and the equation is rearranged with $2xy+k^3$ on the right, the curve looks significantly different, with one large and one small foot, both touching at zero. Why is that?

Comment: Could you provide more detail on your rearrangement process?

Comment: It's a sampling issue; you could try increasing `PlotPoints` or `MaxRecursion`. But why not apply `Plot3D` to $|c(x+iy)|^{1/3}$ instead? It'll be much faster, and then you can increase `MaxRecursion` to like 5 and get a really nice plot very quickly.

Comment: There's a lot of space and not a lot of contours down there. So, while sampling points it is highly unlikely to get points outside and inside the countour near `k = 0`. And ContourPlot is looking for the switch of sign of *lhs*-*rhs* of equation, roughly speaking.

Comment: @Kuba: You took 4 seconds to write a better explanation of the sampling problem. :)

Comment: @Sjoerd, I just captured the results of c[x + y I] and moved 2xy to the RHS. ContourPlot3D[
 Abs[-1 - x + x^2 + x^3 - y^2 - 3 x y^2 + 
    I (-1 + x^2 - y + 2 x y + 3 x^2 y - y^2 - y^3)] == 
  2 x y + k^3, {x, -2.5, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {k, 0, 1.75}]

Comment: @Sjoerd, nevermind. I see that the equation changes with the rearrangement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ContourPlot3D` is not very good at resolving thin features, because it only knows that the feature exists when one of the sampling points happens to land inside it. In general, one thing you can do is to increase `PlotPoints`, which improves the plot but takes a very long time.

```
ContourPlot3D[
 Abs[c[x + I y]] == k^3, {x, -2.5, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {k, 0, 1.75}, 
 Background -> White, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "k"}, PlotPoints -> 20]
```

[image]

In this particular case, though, your plot is equivalent to $k = |c(x+iy)|^{1/3}$, so you could just use `Plot3D` instead. This is much faster because it only has to sample the two-dimensional $xy$ plane rather than the three-dimensional $xyk$ space. Then you can afford to make `MaxRecursion` quite large and it's still really quick to plot.

```
Plot3D[Abs[c[x + I y]]^(1/3), {x, -2.5, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.75},
 Background -> White, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "k"}, ClippingStyle -> None,
 BoxRatios -> 1, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &, #3 &}, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

(I've added a few options to make it look like your original plot.)

Comment: Exceptionally helpful answer.