# Why this region is bad?

Tags: regions, plotting

I want to draw a region but the result of Mathematica is not good. Why?

```
Clear[x1, x2]
g1[x1_, x2_] := x1^4 - x2 + 1;
g2[x1_, x2_] := -x1^3 + x2 - 1;
f[x1_, x2_] := 
  Which[g1[x1, x2] <= 0 && g2[x1, x2] <= 0, (x1 + 1)^2 + (x2 + 1)^2];
fextend[x1_, x2_] := (x1 + 1)^2 + (x2 + 1)^2;

RegionPlot[
 g1[x1, x2] <= 0 && g2[x1, x2] <= 0, {x1, -0.5, 1.2}, {x2, -2, 2.1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Black, Opacity[0.4]]}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

The good region is

[image]

But the result that Mahematica 10 windows 64 bits shows is:
[image]

How can you improve the result?

I was trying but the only solution that I encountered is use Plot instead of RegionPlot.

---

Similar to that trouble is this other in Plot3D, as you can see

```
g1[x1_, x2_] := x1^4 - x2 + 1;
g2[x1_, x2_] := -x1^3 + x2 - 1;
f[x1_, x2_] := 
  Which[g1[x1, x2] <= 0 && g2[x1, x2] <= 0, (x1 + 1)^2 + (x2 + 1)^2];
p3d = Plot3D[f[x1, x2], {x1, -1.5, 1.25}, {x2, -1.5, 2.25}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 10, 
   AxesLabel -> {x1, x2, "f(x1,x2)"}, LabelStyle -> {20, Bold}, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", "Reverse"}], 
   ImageSize -> Large, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 300];
punto = Graphics3D[{Black, PointSize[0.020], Point[{0, 1, f[0, 1]}]}];
Show[p3d, punto]
```

What´s the solution in this case to avoid all that black lines in the limit of region?

[image]

Comment: Because of the same reason as in [44825](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44825/5478)

Comment: @kuba Yes, I solve the problem with PlotPoints->200 I couldn´t imagine that the trouble is for that reason, with a simple function. Thank you.

Comment: @kuba This is solved!! Can you mark as solved?. I can´t mark as solved till 2 days.

Comment: What is the point of the definitions of `f` and `fextend`?  They seem to have nothing to do with the question.  They should probably be removed from the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version
```

> "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 10, 2014)"

```
Clear[x1, x2];
g1[x1_, x2_] := x1^4 - x2 + 1;
g2[x1_, x2_] := -x1^3 + x2 - 1;
f[x1_, x2_] := Which[
   g1[x1, x2] <= 0 && g2[x1, x2] <= 0,
   (x1 + 1)^2 + (x2 + 1)^2];
```

Instead of increasing the number of `PlotPoints` with `RegionPlot`, use `ImplicitRegion`

```
RegionPlot[
 ImplicitRegion[
  g1[x1, x2] <= 0 && g2[x1, x2] <= 0,
  {x1, x2}],
 PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 1.2}, {-2, 2.1}}]
```

[image]

Instead of using `Which` to limit the range of the function, use `RegionFunction`

```
p3d = Plot3D[(x1 + 1)^2 + (x2 + 1)^2,
   {x1, -1.5, 1.25}, {x2, -1.5, 2.25},
   MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},
   Mesh -> 10,
   AxesLabel -> {x1, x2, "f(x1,x2)"},
   LabelStyle -> {20, Bold},
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", "Reverse"}],
   ImageSize -> Large,
   PlotLegends -> Automatic,
   RegionFunction ->
    Function[
     {x1, x2, z},
     g1[x1, x2] <= 0 && g2[x1, x2] <= 0],
   PlotPoints -> 300];
punto = Graphics3D[{
    Black,
    PointSize[0.020],
    Point[{0, 1, f[0, 1]}]}];
Show[p3d, punto, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]